# Django :How to check if a image exists in site media or not?

Tags: python, django

I want to know if a particular file "logo.png" exists in my site_media folder or not

These are my settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/media/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media", "static")
```

I tried `default_storage.exists("/site_media/media/logo.png")` which gives an permission error

I also tried the URLValidator .

Is there any better way to get this done ? Any help is appreciated .

Thanks.

Comment: Why not fix the permission error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default_storage.exists("/site_media/media/logo.png")` approach is almost correct (use `os.path.join` because of the cross-system paths problem). If you have permission problems, then you should fix them (run server as root process?). If you can't, then it is **impossible** to do this.

Comment: You should not run the server as root because someone from the internet can manipulate the http server.